# only showing the overlays that have elements in the viewport

Tags: leaflet

I'd like it if the Layer Control dialog only showed overlays that had elements in the viewport. I setup an example here that illustrates what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/7e84rh06/2/

So in that example the "Cities" overlay has no elements but if you click on "Parks" one element for that overlay does appear. So that overlay has elements in the viewport whereas the "Cities" overlay doesn't. Consequently I'd like it if the dialog only showed "Parks". eg. this:

[image]

...instead of this:

[image]

I'd like this to be dynamic too. eg. if more elements from other overlays enter into the viewport when zooming out then I'd like additional checkboxes to appear in that dialog and if no elements remain in the viewport from an overlay then I'd like that the checkbox corresponding to that overlay to disappear.

Is this even possible?

(SO requires jsfiddle.net links be accompanied by code so...  `token code`)

Comment: You can check whether a given element or even a group is in viewport, see here you have an [example](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#46.checking-if-the-marker-is-in-viewport) if a given marker is in viewport on the basis of which you can show or hide using the layers group style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of Grzgorz T's comments...  all the markers can be grouped together in a [FeatureGroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) and then you can call [getBounds()](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds) on that. Let's save the resultant [LatLngBounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) to `markerBounds`.

Then, you create a function that removes the overlay from the layerControl ([layerControl.removeLayer(cities)](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-removelayer)), calls [map.getBounds()](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds) and then checks to see if the LatLngBounds returned by `getBounds` overlaps with bounds from the FeatureGroup. ie. [map.getBounds().overlaps(markerBounds)](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-overlaps). If they do overlap then you readd the overlay. eg. [layerControl.addOverlay(cities, 'Cities')](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-addoverlay).

You then run this new function once and you create an event handler to run it every time the [moveend event](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend) happens. eg. `map.on('moveend', function() { callFunc(); });`